# Тематичен ли поиск баз данных?

Tags: обсуждение, закрытие-вопросов, тематика

Я хотел закрыть вопрос на поиск баз данных как оффтопик со стандартной формулировкой "поиск библиотек, книг...", но когда вставлял линк на [правила](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), то заметил, что я не точно помню формулировку и *явного* запрета в перечислении именно на базы данных нет.

Поэтому хотел бы уточнить, поиск баз данных это оффтопик для сайта или тематично?

Пример вопроса:

- [Где взять справочник с кодами подразделений, выдающих паспорта?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1052325/213987)
- [Корпус русских стоп слов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/791036/213987)

Comment: Онтопик/оффтопик - теперь я окончательно запутался...

Comment: @РустамГимранов Всё просто: онтопик = тематично, оффтопик = нетематично (закрываем и удаляем с сайта).

Comment: "Поделитесь, где найти такую базу?" - в вопросе отсутсутствует главное, что было сделано, чтобы базу найти. Хотя бы по этому данный вопрос, оффтоп. "Поиск по ключевым словам: база данных фмс код подразделение - не дал результата" - было бы уже лучше.  Помоему надо поступить просто - сделать тему-закрывашку со списком легальных баз данных и все новые вопросы закрывать как дубли.

Comment: -1 за третье "слово". Здесь не все знают английский язык, к слову.

Comment: +1 ибо все, кто читают мету - знают что такое "онтопик". И, главное, что тема вполне актуальная.

Comment: @AntonMenshov, edem вы не можете прикрываться "всеми", ибо я первом комментарии намёком попросил у автора уточнений, хоть и знаком с английским ) К сожалению потерли поясняющий комментарий.

Comment: @РустамГимранов :) не буду. я даже абсолютно за исправление на "тематичен" - звучит лучше и понятнее. Просто, на мой взгляд, это не повод минусовать конкретно в данном случае. Опять же, на мой взгляд.

Comment: По моему нет особой разницы между тематичен/онтопик. В русском языке нет такого слова. Я перешл сюда только потому, что не понял, что значит "тематичен ли вопрос" =)
Имхо, было бы правильнее написать "Слеует ли закрывать вопросы поиска баз данных как "поиск библиотек" или что-то в таком духе

Answer (score 5):

Никто не отвечает, поэтому просто свое мнение выскажу: это не та категория вопросов, с которой нужно было бы жёстко бороться.

На фоне массы вопросов по метке JavaScript (как щёлкнуть здесь, чтобы появилось "тута" и исчезло "тама") - подобные вопросы [поиск-данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85) редко встречаются, и часто без принятого ответа.

То есть они все равно спустя некоторое время будут удалены системой без нашего вмешательства.